# Add configurable option to cart

Tags: magento-1, addtocart

I am able to add the simple associated product of a configurable product using the code below.

```
                        <?php
                        $purchasableProductId = $product->getId();
                        if($product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
                            $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($product);
                            $simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
                            foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product) {
                                $purchasableProductId = $simple_product->getId();
                                break; //Break after first iteration since most configurable products have the first product as the most popular choice
                                //echo $simple_product->getId() . " - " . $simple_product->getName() . " - " . Mage::helper('core')->currency($simple_product->getPrice()) . "\n";
                            }
                        endif;
                        ?>
                        <form action="/checkout/cart/add/product/<?php echo $purchasableProductId ?>" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1" /><!--onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product); ?>')" --> 
                            <button type="submit" style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; width:99%;" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') . ' - $' . number_format($product->getPrice(), 2) ?>" class="button btn-cart"  ><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') . ' - $' . number_format($product->getPrice(), 2) ?></span></span></button>
                        </form> 
                    </div>
```

My problem is that it is not added as an option, so the product does not show the parent configurable product's image in the cart as it would had I used the product view page to add the option to the cart.

How can I modify the form above to add the product to cart as an option rather than an independent product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iUseMagentoNow

you need to get configurable product varien attribute and send it send to cart simple product attribute to cart

get configurable attribute of product configurable

```
$AllowAttributes=$conf->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getConfigurableAttributes($conf);
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($AllowAttributes);
```

then create a dynamic form input fields

```
   <?php
    foreach($_attributes as $_attribute):
    $productAttribute   = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
/* here varien value for simple products */
    $attributeValue     = $simple_product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
    ?>

            <input type="hidden"  name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" value="<?php echo $attributeValue;  ?>" />
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```